# multiple VirtualHosts and https (not multiple ssl virtualhosts)

Tags: apache, ssl, https, virtualhost

I have multiple VirtualHosts (about 20) on the same instance of Apache, as well as one ssl host. now I've currently got the ssl virtual host set onto a subdomain (ssl.domain.tld).

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache/htdocs/domainfolder/ssl"
ServerName ssl.domain.tld:443
```

Now https works fine when I load one of the applications, for instance phpMyAdmin when going to https://ssl.domain.tld/pma which is good... it works. However a customer has just pointed out that when he goes to another host (lets say https://www.anotherdomain.tld/pma) it still loads the application.

Now I only want these applications to be run from only 1 domain name, not all of them, which its currently doing.

I have no idea how to fix this.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You should get an account on ServerFault. This is not really a programming question. (This question will probably be migrated there if closed for migration.)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise. My Mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Alias` for phpMyAdmin isn't located within a `VirtualHost` section, but is set globally instead.

Depending on your installation, this may be due to the fact the phpMyAdmin is installed separately from your main Apache Httpd packages and done via a separate configuration file (for example `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`). For the configuration you're after, you may need to move its content explicitly within your SSL VirtualHost section.

Comment: Well, its not just phpMyAdmin, its everything. As I said in the previous post I have lots of virtualhosts, but I only want `ssl.thisdomain.tld` to use https, rather than all domains. `www.otherdomain.tld` doesn't have a directory called pma within it, yet if you type url `https://www.otherdomain.tld/pma` it acts as though it does.

Comment: Options that are not within any `VirtualHost` section usually apply to all virtual hosts. Check your global configuration options.